# How do i make a switch click in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I want to make it so that once clicking on a button it will make something and when you click on it again it will make something else.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ai : MonoBehaviour {
    bool stopstate = false;
    Animator _anim;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        _anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        //_animation = GetComponent<Animation> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Z)) {

            if (stopstate == false) {
                stopstate = true;
                _anim.Stop ();
            } else {

                stopstate = false;
                _anim.StartPlayback ();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Once I clicked on Z Stop() but if I press it again on Z now Play.

The problem is that the code is in the Update function so I use a break point once I pressed the Z key it stopped on the _anim.StartPlayback (); but it should get there on the second time i click on Z.

Second problem is when it does the line _anim.StartPlayback (); it's not making the character to continue walking from the point it was stopped.

_anim.Stop(); really stop it but StartPlayback() not make it continue.

Comment: Use a boolean to keep track of the state?

Answer (score 1):

The best option for you is a `CheckBox` Create a checkbox in the front-end( let it be `chkToggle`) and then Change its appearance as button using the following code(after initialize or in page load):

```
chkToggle.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;
```

So it will be like a button in the front end. Then you can use the following code to do something if it is checked and do other thing if it is not checked.

```
private void chkToggle_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if((sender as CheckBox).Checked)
    {
          // Do something
    }
    else
    {
        // Do other thing
    }
}
```

if it is a single method then you can use a global variable of type `boolean` to keep the state and toggle them; then the code will be like the following:

```
bool currentState; // false will be the default value
void Update () 
{
   if(currentState)
   {
     // Dosomething
   }
   else
   {
    // Do some other thing
   }
    currentState = !currentState; // toggle the state
}
```